# Why is this navbar hover not working when using :hover in css?

Tags: css

Why when I try to color the background of a specific navbar section on http://ntsu.unioncloudsandpit.org does it not work via CSS?

I have tried:

```
#green-menu-wrapper:hover {
background:#95C11F;
}

Along with different selectors

#top-nav-level-one-green:hover
.top-nav-level-one-your-say:hover
```

Comment: Could you produce a [mcve]? The site you link to is a work in progress, right? That would make it a moving target for everyone trying to take a look at it. And it's well over 1000 lines of code, most of which is probably not necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: if you are adding custom css to interact alongside already existing template css, try to add *!important* at the end, i.e. `background:#95C11F !important;`. Sometimes, depending on what gets loaded first etc., the template css will have priority.

Comment: In adding to martins comment, use classes instead of Ids. It would save a lot of time in future

Comment: Don't add !important to just everything. It wrecks havoc with all cascading rules and makes maintenance a lot harder. Having !important all over the place is a signal that you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I view your page,  I think you are missing a semi-colon and try to add the "-color"

```
< !--Your Say-- > #green-menu-wrapper:hover {
    background: #95c11f !important
}
```

try to use:

```
#green-menu-wrapper:hover {
    background-color: #95c11f;
}
```